# Pages are reloading in WPF Tabbed Document Interface

Tags: wpf

I am creating a desktop application in WPF. I am trying to use tabs for showing multiple pages. I am NOT using MVVM. The problem is, when I click on a menu item say Student_Info, a new tab is created and Student page is displayed. But when I switch to another tab, and get back to Student tab, Student page is reloaded and all data of form is lost. How can resolve this problem. 
Please note [I am using this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem) for customized tab item.
My code for adding new tab is below:

```
    private void Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        ClosableTab tabItem = new ClosableTab();
        switch (btn.Tag)
        {
            case "Student":                    
                pageStudent student = new pageStudent();
                frame.Content = student;                                        
                tabItem.Title = "Student Info";
                break;

            case "Result":
                pageResult result = new pageResult();
                frame.Content = result;
                tabItem.Title = "Result";
                break;
        }
        tabItem.Content = frame;
        tabControl1.Items.Add(tabItem);
        tabItem.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in your Click event handler, you're creating new instances of your "student" and "result" pages.

What you should do instead is creating those two pages somewhere else (on the `Load` event of your page for example) and, in the menu click event, you should simply switch to those tabs instead of recreating them.

Comment: Yes I know that I have to modify this code to avoid recreating of if tab is already created. But this code or button is clicked only first time to create a new tab. But I am talking about the problem of switching tab items. This code is not hitting on tab header click. What I want to say, there are two tabs, one is Student and second is Result. I am entering student data on student form, and switched to Result tab, when I come back to Student tab by clicking on Student tab item header, Student page is reloaded and all data get lost.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you're not doing anything in the click event of the tabs. Are you sure you don't have anything that might recreate the page instances?

Comment: Yes there is not event on click of tab item. There is just close button click event to close the tab. I am using this custom tab item class for tab item without any modification. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem

Comment: I have just noticed that when I come back to tab, the page loaded event is called, but constructor of page is not called. I have stopped the page loaded event code to run after first call by using a flag and now the problem is resolved. I is new for me that page loaded event is called every time when tab is got focused.

Comment: This is standard behavior with the loaded event, it's called every time the element is going to be rendered. Maybe you can migrate your logic to the initialized event. Check [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikehillberg/2006/09/19/the-loaded-event-and-the-initialized-event/) for more information on those events.

Comment: Instead of adding a "thanks" comment, please use the upvote button ;). Also, please consider marking this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that when I come back to tab, the page_loaded event is called every time, but constructor of page is not called. I have stopped the page_loaded event code to execute after first call by using a flag and now the problem is resolved. It is new thing for me that page loaded event is called every time when tab is got focused.